# org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am getting a exception while working in json . My JSONPresr class is as follow

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {
 static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(" value in json sting"+json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data [" + e.getMessage()+"] "+json);
            System.out.println(" error is here");

        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }

    }
```

I am getting my data by these code

```
          String TAG_user_detail = "user_details";
              String TAG_user_id = "user_id";
             String TAG_user_name = "user_name";
             String TAG_user_phone = "user_phone";
             String TAG_ref_id = "ref_id";
             JSONArray user_detail_jsonarray = null;
             JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

             // getting JSON string from URL
             JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
             try {
                 // Getting Array of Contacts
                 user_detail_jsonarray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_user_detail);

                 // looping through All Contacts
                 for(int i = 0; i < user_detail_jsonarray.length(); i++){
                     JSONObject c = user_detail_jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                     // Storing each json item in variable
                     int id = c.getInt(TAG_user_id);
                     System.out.println("user id from json"+id);

                     String name_fromjson = c.getString(TAG_user_name);
                     System.out.println("user name from json"+name_fromjson);

                     int phone_no_fromjson = c.getInt(TAG_user_phone);
                     System.out.println("user phone from json"+phone_no_fromjson);

                     int ref_id_fromjson = c.getInt(TAG_ref_id);
                     System.out.println("user ref id from json"+ref_id_fromjson);





                 }
             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

But i am countiniously getting Exception in this line

```
    user_detail_jsonarray = json.getJSONArray(TAG_user_detail);
```

My Stake Trace message is as

```
       {"ref_id":1295,"user_name":"chand","user_phone":"9620085675","user_id":"1"} at user_details of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I tried many link but unfortunately i am not able to get my result. Please any body just help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance to all

Comment: you are getting JSONObject for `TAG_user_detail` not an array

Comment: Will you please post some code

Comment: Which code? put your complete JSON.

Comment: @ Pankaj...This is my json

Comment: {"user_details":{"user_id":"1","user_name":"chand","user_phone":"9620085675","ref_id":6386}}

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Its clear from error that you are trying to convert Json Object into Json array. That should not.

Here is the code to read your JSON response.

```
String json = "Assuming that here is your JSON response"; 
try {
    JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONObject userDetails = parentObject.getJSONObject("user_details"); 

    //And then read attributes like             
    String name = userDetails.getString("user_name"); 
    String phone = userDetails.getString("user_phone");
    String id = userDetails.getString("re‌​f_id");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Above code is for `{"user_details":{"user_id":"1","user_name":"chand","user_phone":"9620085675","re‌​f_id":6386}}` JSON.

Comment: Ok.. sorry man... i am on verge of insane condition..but i upvoted  you

Comment: hey... hope you will get ride on those.. :) all the best

Comment: Hey pankaj.. i am getting another issue that is.. Without any doubt your suggestion is really very help-full for me. While i am parsing {"user_details":{"ref_id":"chand09","user_id":"1","user_name":"chand","user_phone":"9620085675"}}. I am getting all the info from json except "ref_id".

Comment: Check if value for that tag, exists. because when I run the code its giving me the value of ref_id too. and if value is there try to change the ref_id to another string.

Comment: you are awesome guy..before your suggestion i just change ref_id to another string it work for me.when i get back i saw your sugestion.

Comment: i also facing the same issue will u tell me the how can i change the return type @DJhon because i written the code for the array and json is 
**{"result":[{"id":"1","name":"Zim","image":"http:\/\/studylogic.net\/wp.jpg"}]}**

Comment: @DhruvTyagi  Please have look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825184/how-to-parse-json-response-using-jackson-in-android

Comment: @DJhon actually I fix it it bt I have another query that I want to send some String and in return my response is JsonArray but the problem is the JsonArray syntax would not allow for that

Answer (score 7):

Learn from exception

```
org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

You are getting this exception   `org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`
because you are trying to convert `JSONObject to JSONArray` which is not possible.

`{` represents json object node

`[` represents json array node

Comment: thanks for your response... Will you please post some code here,,,,, It will be help full for me

Comment: @BlueGreen try by parsing JSONObject !

Comment: @BlueGreen like if you want to retrieve user name than use: String name_fromjson=(String) json.get("user_name"); no need of for loop as well as of jsonarray !

Answer (score 3):

your jsondata is json object format. change this line

```
JsonObject user_detail_jsonobj = json.getJSONObject(TAG_user_detail);
```