# Can't convert this string to JSON

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm trying to convert the following string into a JSONArray.

```
 try {
        BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                openFileInput(mFileName), "UTF-8"));
        String inputString;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputString = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(inputString + "\n");
        }

        JSONArray JArray = new JSONArray(stringBuffer.toString());
        for(int i = 0; i < JArray.length() + 1; i++) {
            JSONObject obj = JArray.getJSONObject(i);
            mWrite = mWrite + obj.toString() + ",";

        }
```

The problem is I get this error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"friends":[{"name":"paul","level":"56.73","focus_level":"53.55","focus_points":32129,"max_streak":8760,"total_days_coded":780,"total_flow_states":1081,"time_spent":2109716,"programming_now":true,"current_language":"RegExp","streaking_now":false,"platforms":{"Linux":{"percent_work":0.88,"points":22,"time":6932},"Windows 7":{"percent_work":3.26,"points":82,"time":17326},"linux":{"percent_work":48.74,"points":1237,"time":1196665},"windows":{"percent_work":47.12,"points":1196,"time":890146}},"languages":{"ANY":{"level":"0.36","points":5},"ActionScript":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"ApacheConf":{"level":"0.09","points":1},"ApacheConfig":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"Bash":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"CSS":{"level":"1.23","points":30},"CoffeeScript":{"level":"0.73","points":14},"Diff":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"ECMA Script Level 4":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"GenericSQL":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"Git Commit Message":{"level":"0.09","points":1},"GitHub Markdown":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"Groovy":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"HTML":{"level":"4.32","points":256},"HTML (Django)":{"level":"0.05","points":0},"HTML (Rails)":{"level":"0.09","points":1},"HTML 5":{"level":"1.27","points":32},"Handlebars":{"level":"0.91","points":19},"Host Config":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"JAVA":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"JSON":{"level":"0.91","points":20},"Java":{"level":"0.27","points":4},"JavaScript":{"level":"8.18","points":833},"JavaScript 1":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"Language: JAVA":{"level":"0.05","points":0},"Lisp":{"level":"0.09","points":1},"Markdown":{"level":"1.59","points":46},"MySQL":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"Null Grammar":{"level":"0.05","points":1},"PHP":{"level":"11.36","points":1550},"Plain":{"level":"7.41","points":692},"Plain Text":{"level":"2.59","points":104},"PlainTasks":{"level":"1.91","points":61},"Python":{"level":"3.32","points":158},"R":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"RegExp":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"Ruby":{"level":"0.41","points":6},"SCSS":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"SQL":{"level":"0.32","points":5},"SVN Edit":{"level":"0.23","points":3},"Shell":{"level":"0.14","points":1},"Shell-Unix-Generic":{"level":"0.36","points":6},"Syntaxes":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"TEXT":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"TypeScript":{"level":"0.36","points":5},"XML":{"level":"0.86","points":19},"XSL":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"YAML":{"level":"0.14","points":1},"color":{"level":"1.09","points":25},"laravel-blade":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"regex":{"level":"0.00","points":0},"syntax":{"level":"0.23","points":3},"yaml":{"level":"0.00","points":0}}}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Does anyone know what might be happening here? I'm very new to JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850969/org-json-jsonobject-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root of your JSON is an object, not an array. Try this:

```
JSONArray JArray = new JSONObject(stringBuffer.toString()).getJSONArray("friends");
```

Comment: thank you so very much! how can I learn more about JSONArray in a concise manner?

Answer (score 0):

I opened the string in an Viewer (JOE - JSON Object Explorer) available in Google Play. It shows a root object friends containing an array. If you are new to JSON, JOE might help you to understand better.